# He delivers top notch (advise/advice)?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I understand advice is a noun while advise is a verb. Advise is the act of giving advice. Despite knowing what they mean, I am still confuse how to use them correctly.

I came across this sentence which is written by someone who is very learned in English. They wrote:

> He delivers top notch **advise** and service.

If I were to write this, I will use ***advice*** instead.

-

On another part of the article, they use **advise** as follow:

> They are meticulous **in** their service and **advise**!

I will probably write it as below:

> They are meticulous **with** their service and **advice**!

In the above examples, can you correct me on why **advise** is use and not **advice**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advise** is the verb while **Advice** is the noun. ([Source](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/advise-advice/))

> He **advised** me to eat properly.
>   He earns by giving relationship **advice**.

I think that your versions are correct, and the original ones are wrong. It might have been a typing mistake or such.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't very confident with the usage of these two words and often doubt myself. Most likely an autocorrect or typo on their part.